# Eclipse SWT java.lang.StackOverflowError : why my listener executes many times?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, swt-awt

I am working on eclipse plugin. I create an extension point on eclipse plugin. I've added a dropdown list. So I implemented a listener to know when the value changed and execute my logic. Here the snippet of the extension point :

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertyTabs">
        <propertyTabs contributorId="com.ibm.xtools.modeler.ui.properties">
            <propertyTab
                label="My new Label"
                category="Core"
                afterTab="modeleditor.property.tab.AdvancedTab"
                id="com.test.plugin.tabs.MyNewTab"/>
        </propertyTabs>
    </extension> 
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.propertySections">
        <propertySections contributorId="com.ibm.xtools.modeler.ui.properties">
            <propertySection
                class="com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection"
                tab="com.test.plugin.tabs.MyNewTab"
                filter="com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection$Filter"
                id="com.bnpp.ism.test.profile.tabs.MyNewTab">
            </propertySection>
        </propertySections>
    </extension>
```

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ComboViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelectionChangedListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.SelectionChangedEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.TabbedPropertySheetPage;
import org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Enumeration;
import org.eclipse.uml2.uml.NamedElement;

public class MyNewTabSection extends SuperSection{

    private ComboViewer comboViewer;
    private ISelectionChangedListener comboViewerSelectionListener;
    private Label myLabel;
    private final static List<String> myValues = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("FIRST","TWO","THREE"));
    public static class Filter extends AbstractFilter{

    public Filter() {
        super();
    }
}

    @Override
    public void createControls(Composite parent,TabbedPropertySheetPage tabbedPropertySheetPage) {
        super.createControls(parent,tabbedPropertySheetPage);
        addLabel();
        addComboViewer();

    @Override
    protected void addListeners() {
        comboViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(getComboViewerSelectionListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected void removeListeners() {
        comboViewer.removeSelectionChangedListener(getComboViewerSelectionListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean acceptElement(EObject element) {
        return element instanceof Enumeration;
    }

    private void addComboViewer() {

        FormData data;
        comboViewer = new ComboViewer(composite);
        data = new FormData();
        data.left = new FormAttachment(myLabel,10);
        data.top = new FormAttachment(15,110);
        comboViewer.getCombo().setText("                                           ");
        comboViewer.getCombo().setLayoutData(data);
        comboViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
        comboViewer.setInput(myValues);

    }

    private void addReferenceTypeCombo() {

        FormData data;
        comboViewer = new ComboViewer(composite);
        data = new FormData();
        data.left = new FormAttachment(myLabel,10);// 10,110
        data.width = 100;
        data.top = new FormAttachment(15,110);
        comboViewer.getCombo().setText("                                           ");
        comboViewer.getCombo().setLayoutData(data);
        comboViewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
        NomenclatureTypeView[] values = NomenclatureTypeView.values();
        comboViewer.setInput(myValues);

    }

    private void addLabel() {
        FormData data;
        nomenclatureLabel = new Label(composite,0);
        data = new FormData();
        data.left = new FormAttachment(10,110);
        data.top = new FormAttachment(15,110);
        myLabel.setLayoutData(data);
        myLabel.setBackground(white);
        myLabel.setText("My Label text");
    }


    private ISelectionChangedListener getComboViewerSelectionListener() {

        if (comboViewerSelectionListener == null) {

            comboViewerSelectionListener = new ISelectionChangedListener(){

                @Override
                public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {

                    IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
                    Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();
                    final String value = firstElement.toString();
                    Object firstElementA = comboViewer.getElementAt(0);
                    if (firstElement != null) {
                        comboViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(firstElement));
                    }

                    // some logic
                }
            };
        }
        return comboViewerSelectionListener;
    }


    @Override
    protected void initInternalInput(EObject element) {
        this.element = (NamedElement) element;

    }

    @Override
    protected void resetInternalInput() {
        this.element = null;
    }   
}
```

When I click on the Tab I can see the dropdown list with my value (ONE, TWO, THREE). But when I select a value of the list the listener run many times. It's strange because I just select one time the value.
It runs the listener code many times until having the following exception :

```
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:3877)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo.windowProc(Combo.java:2058)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4545)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessage(OS.java:3012)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo.select(Combo.java:1386)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ComboViewer.listSetSelection(ComboViewer.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractListViewer.setSelectionToWidget(AbstractListViewer.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelectionToWidget(StructuredViewer.java:1680)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1636)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
    at com.test.plugin.sections.myNewTabSection$2.selectionChanged(myNewTabSection.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
    at com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection$2.selectionChanged(MyNewTabSection.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
    at com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection$2.selectionChanged(MyNewTabSection.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
    at com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection$2.selectionChanged(MyNewTabSection.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
    at com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection$2.selectionChanged(MyNewTabSection.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
    at com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection$2.selectionChanged(MyNewTabSection.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
    at com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection$2.selectionChanged(MyNewTabSection.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
    at com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection$2.selectionChanged(MyNewTabSection.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
    at com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection$2.selectionChanged(MyNewTabSection.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
    at com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection$2.selectionChanged(MyNewTabSection.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
    at com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection$2.selectionChanged(MyNewTabSection.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
    at com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection$2.selectionChanged(MyNewTabSection.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
    at com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection$2.selectionChanged(MyNewTabSection.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1638)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.setSelection(Viewer.java:392)
    at com.test.plugin.sections.MyNewTabSection$2.selectionChanged(MyNewTabSection.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:162)
```

Comment: Certainly `comboViewer.setSelection` in your listener trigger a `SelectionChange` event that will be caught by your listener which trigger ... and so on

Comment: Great ! thanks. Could you write answer so i'll tick as correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly `comboViewer.setSelection` in your listener trigger a `SelectionChange` event that will be caught by your listener which trigger ... and so on